# How to insert record in to oracle table using shell script?

Tags: database, oracle, shell

I want to insert a record into an Oracle table by using a shell script.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SQL*Plus](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html) for that:

```
sqlplus user/password@database <<EOF
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE...
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a multiple ways to insert data in oracle database from unix command prompt.

1) From command prompt

```
[oracle@OLE1]$ echo "insert into EMP values (7001,'TESTUSER','CLERK',7902,sysdate,2500,800,10);"|sqlplus -s scott/tiger;

auto COMMIT upon EXIT.
```

2) From shell Script

```
vi insert_stm.sh

    echo "Insert Data into EMP table of scott."
    sqlplus -s /nolog<<-EOF
    conn scott/tiger;
    set heading on feedback on;
    insert into EMP values (7001,'TESTUSER','CLERK',7902,sysdate,2500,800,10);
    commit; 
    EOF

    echo "Insert Done."
:wq

[oracle@OLE1 Desktop]$ sh insert_stm.sh
Insert Data into EMP table of scott.

1 row created.


Commit complete.

Insert done.
[oracle@OLE1 Desktop]$
```

Note: If you are using remote database please use "@" symbol like:

sqlplus -s scott/tiger@stringname;

conn scott/tiger@stringname;